# Restore full control of registry key (and subkeys) to SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

There is a registry key (and maybe more) that have had SYSTEM either removed or explicitly denied permission. I need to do this programmatically from the SYSTEM account (Powershell, VBS, command line all, Python all work).

Comment: Instead of asking for code, show some screen shots of the broken permissions and screen shots of what you want (from a good computer) and then ask how you can get from A to B using the command line. People will respond with commands that you can use from Cmd, PowerShell, or whatever.

Comment: I searched on `command line give system account full control to registry key` and got some usefuls hits, such [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/change-registry-values-permissions) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/331046/change-permissions-on-registry-key-via-command-line)

Comment: https://petri.com/reset-default-security-acls-windows/

Comment: Am curious if you're in domain environment with GPO's to push GPO solution. Also, delete the local GPO folders of `"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"` and `"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy"` to remove any local GPO settings causing your problem. I've seen those folders become corrupt and not allow domain pushed policies to set so consider purging just for giggles too. If `gpupdate /force` gets errors, purge those folders then rerun `gpupdate`. A system repair would be good if you can mass scale it and time out accordingly not affect production machines at production hours.

Comment: I would be curious to hear what you see or what specifically indicates the registry permission is the issue with `SYSTEM` access. It wasn't an admin mistake made vs someone actually being malicious. Some app or program error'ing out, something not installing or repairing such as AV/Endpoint Security or something like that right? Just curious what may be accurate here for what is going on or is assumed going on? Like a virus infection vs disgruntled IT admin, etc. Curious if there is such a story or pure "not sure/don't know for sure" type thing? Mistakes happen and we learn so no shame if so.

Comment: This was done to hide from 3rd party security tools that run under the SYSTEM account. Now we cant use the tool to fix these broken keys. This can be reproduced by setting an explicit deny on the SYSTEM account on a registry key. Then use something like PSEXEC -i -s and try reading said registry key.

Answer (score 0):

I understand registry permissions were modified which should never
have been touched, now causing problems in running Windows.

If you have enabled System Restore, the simplest solution would be to
rollback to before these changes were done.
For more information see the article
[How to Use System Restore in Windows 10, 11, 7, and 8](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/).

If this is not possible, the next step would be to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This will set all Windows components to a known state, and with some luck
may also fix the registry permissions. This is the same as doing a
major Windows update, and will conserve data and apps.

If nothing helps, then the only option left is to install Windows from
scratch. Save your data beforehand. You will need to reinstall all apps.

Comment: This was done by a malicious person across an unknown number of machines.

Comment: Apologies - answer was modified.